# How to generate 2 letter words using a function in python?

Tags: python

hi so im using python and i'm trying to create a function that lets me generate words made up of 2 letters. i also want to count how many of the words generated are actually in the dictionary.

this is what i have so far:

```
alphabet = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
            'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
count1 = 0
text = " "

def find2LetterWords():
    for letter in alphabet:
        text += letter
        for letter in alphabet:
            text +=letter
    print text
```

this is the code i have written so far and i know its not right. i was just experimenting. so yea it would be great if u could help me out. thx.

Comment: Using differently named loop control variables would be a good start, as would moving your `print` statement into the first `for` loop level and resetting text on each iteration. Otherwise, `text` will just be `aaabacadae...` and so on and so forth.

Comment: instead of that alphabet tuple, you might want to use [string.ascii_lowercase](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase)

Comment: @edwin im new to programming so im not sure what a loop control variable is. and yea i'll fix the print statement as well. thx.

Comment: @321: He means you are using `letter` in both `for` loops.

Comment: @junuxx would that make it easier? id rather not try that as i'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer edited based on comments:

```
def find2LetterWords():
     #this generates all possible 2-letter combos with a list comprehension
     words = [first + second for second in alphabet for first in alphabet]
     #create a new list with only those words that are in your_dictionary (a list)
     real_words = [word for word in words if word in your_dictionary]
     return real_words
```

If you want a nice one liner, with no function:

```
[word for word in [first + second for second in alphabet for first in alphabet] if word in your_dictionary]
```

Obviously, replace `your_dictionary` with whatever the name of your dictionary is.

Comment: Well, that depends on what kind of container your dictionary is. Are all the words in a list?

Comment: thx for ur help. this is great. i realized that part of the problem wast that i wasnt nesting the for loop propely. ok so i have a dictionary. so how exactly would i count the words generated that actually are in the dictionary? Akavall showed me this code:  counts = sum(len(k) == 2 for k in my_dict.iterkeys()) but im not using itertool. im not sure how i would do it if i used a loop like urs.

Comment: ok thx a bunch. this was great. ive chosen ur code as the best answer b/c it was simpler for me to understand. plus, instead of the ascii, the letters need to be in a list.

Comment: `list(set())` is a total waste, there aren't any duplicates.

Comment: @Junuxx Correct you are. In retrospect, I don't know why I thought there would be. Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

`product` from the `itertools` module is exactly what you need to generate a list of all possible 2-letter words.

```
from itertools import product

alphabet = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')

two_letter_words = product(alphabet, alphabet)

for word in two_letter_words:
    print word
```

To compare which one of those are in the dictionary you will need to get that from somewhere else

Comment: +1, but you can do `''.join(word)` so a string is printed instead of a tuple, minor point.

Comment: good call with `itertools`. while using it, important to be aware that product will ultimately yield 26^2 entries, so while this will definitely be efficient in terms of memory (as a generator function), it may not be the best algorithm for the problem (esp with longer words).

Comment: @toote im actually new to python and programming for that matter so i dont know what itertool is. could u explain it to me plz? thx. and i also noticed that u didnt use a function. how would i do this using a function?

Comment: @321: [Itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) is a builtin Python module with handy things such as the `product` function and more. You should accept this answer, it's clearly the best as my comparison shows.

Comment: @junuxx thx for the explanation. the thing is that i need to use functions. but otherwise it looks much simpler.

Comment: srry junuxx. hodofhod's code was easier for me to understand. thx anyways though. i still learned alot fromu guys

Answer (score 5):

Another way, with a list comprehension:

```
words = [x+y for x in alphabet for y in alphabet]
```

Or without typing out the alphabet yourself:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as a
words = [x+y for x in a for y in a]
```

Let's do a comparison of the answers by xvatar,  Toote and me:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase as a
import timeit

def nestedFor():
    w = []
    for l1 in a:
        for l2 in a:
            word = l1+l2
            w.append(word)
    return w

def nestedForIter():
    w = []
    for l1 in a:
        for l2 in a:
            yield l1+l2

def withProduct():
    return product(a,a)

def listComp():
    return [x+y for x in a for y in a]

def generatorComp():
    return (x+y for x in a for y in a)

# return list
t1 =  timeit.Timer(stmt="nestedFor()",
                   setup = "from __main__ import nestedFor")
t2 = timeit.Timer(stmt="list(withProduct())",
                   setup = "from __main__ import withProduct")
t3 = timeit.Timer(stmt="listComp()",
                   setup = "from __main__ import listComp")

# return iterator
t4 = timeit.Timer(stmt="nestedForIter()",
                   setup = "from __main__ import nestedForIter")
t5 = timeit.Timer(stmt="withProduct()",
                   setup = "from __main__ import withProduct")
t6 = timeit.Timer(stmt="generatorComp()",
                   setup = "from __main__ import generatorComp")

n = 100000

print 'Methods returning lists:'
print "Nested for loops:   %.3f" % t1.timeit(n)
print "list(product):      %.3f" % t2.timeit(n)
print "List comprehension: %.3f\n" % t3.timeit(n)

print 'Methods returning iterators:'
print "Nested for iterator:     %.3f" % t4.timeit(n)
print "itertools.product:       %.3f" % t5.timeit(n)
print "Generator comprehension: %.3f\n" % t6.timeit(n)
```

Results:

> Methods returning lists:
>   Nested for loops:   13.362
>   list(product):      4.578
>   List comprehension: 7.231
>
> Methods returning generators:
>   Nested for iterator:     0.045
>   itertools.product:       0.212
>   Generator comprehension: 0.066

In other words, definitely use `itertools.product` if you really need a full list. However, a generator is faster and requires less memory, and will probably suffice.

The relative slowness of itertools.product as an iterator is unexpected, considering that [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) says that it is *equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression*. It seems there is some overhead.

Comment: For `nestedFor()` try returning a generator. It actually performs better than `itertools.product` on my machine. Thanks for doing the timings.

Comment: thx. ur way actually is much simpler but the down side is that my code needs to be a function.

Comment: @Akavall: Good suggestion, I'll add it to the comparison.

Comment: @321: See `listComp` in the comparison code for my approach in the form of a function.

Comment: @Akavall: Note that the generator comprehension also outperforms itertools.product

Comment: @Junuxx, I see. Thanks again. I am actually surprised by the results, I thought what `itertools.product` returns (`<type 'itertools.product'>`) is very much like a generator. Do you know why `Nested generator` and `Generator Comprehension` perform better that `itertools.product`?

Comment: @Akavall: I'd enlighten you if I could, but I'm as surprised as you.

Comment: Updated the comparison - I was comparing methods that returned the full list with one that returned an iterator. The current results show a fairer comparison, but the conclusions remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find2LetterWords():
    words = []
    for first in alphabet:
        for second in alphabet:
            new_word = first + second
            words.append(new_word)
    print words
    return words
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the question is already well answered, but here is the second.

> i also want to count how many of the words generated are actually in
>   the dictionary.

Actually this is very easy. You know that you list of words has all possible combinations in it. And you know that dictionary keys are unique; therefore, key that is two characters long must be in the word list. All you need to do is count number of keys that have length 2.

```
counts = sum(len(k) == 2 for k in my_dict.iterkeys())
```

Comment: ahh i see. thx. so i just import a dictionary and do this in the for loop, right? makes sense.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "do this in the for loop", all you have to do is use the for loop that is in my code.